How to use list of pairs as parameters for a query in postgres
I am using java spring boot with postgres as my database. I have a table called current logs with many fields. I also have 2 lists one for team ids and one for event dates. Now team_id[0] corresponds to event_date[0] and so on..... I want to write a query which gives me all the records which satisfies a particular set of conditions(you can see them below) on a particular pair. I have tried writing this code :
    @Query(
  value =
      "with pairs as ("
          + "  select unnest(ARRAY[:teamIds]) as team_id, unnest(ARRAY[:eventDates]) as event_date"
          + ") "
          + "select * from current_logs cl "
          + "inner join current_logs_settings cls on cl.current_logs_settings_id = cls.id "
          + "INNER JOIN pairs p ON cls.team_id = p.team_id "
          + "where cls.university_id = :universityId "
          + "and cl.period_start_date <= p.event_date "
          + "and cl.period_end_date >= p.event_date",
  nativeQuery = true)
List<CurrentLogs> findUsersByTeamIdsAndEventDates(
  @Param("universityId") Long universityId,
  @Param("teamIds") List<Long> teamIds,
  @Param("eventDates") List<LocalDate> eventDates);

But when I tried this code, it gives me SQL grammar exception possibly because of the ARRAY keyword used on my java lists. Is there anyway I can get my required solution?

I don't think this can be made to work with JPQL.  Instead, you should either use a native Postgres query, or else, maintain a small table in your database with the pairs data.

Try without ARRAY unnest(:teamIds) and also enable SHOW-SQL in yml/properties file spring.jpa.show-sql=true, so that you can check the actual query that gets fired.

@SharadPaul ... but that would change the query, right?

@TimBiegeleisen, I am already using a native query

By the way, text blocks

Another way to avoid nativeQuery is to use CriteriaQuery
